# Parent folder name in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to show file root/parent in the `DataGridView`, but I don't know how. I listed all files that are in subdirectories in one root folder, but I'd also like that every file has its parent folder shown in `DataGridView`. Is there anyway to get this information from `System.IO` library?

This is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = LocationX;
    s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@LocationX, "#", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {   
            dt.Columns.Add("Paren Folder Name");  
            dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Version");
            dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
            dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
            dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
        }

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
        FileSystemInfo f1 = new FileInfo(s1[i]);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Root"] = f1.????????     //is it possible to do show parent folder this way?
        dr["File_Name"] = f1.Name;
        dr["File_Type"] = f1.Extension;
        dr["File_Size"] = (f.Length / 1024).ToString();
        dr["Create_Date"] = f1.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FileInfo.Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory.aspx) to get directory name of file:

```
dr["Root"] = f.Directory.Name;
```

Also move columns creation out of the loop. I think loop should be used only for adding data to table.

---

```
dt.Columns.Add("Paren Folder Name");  
dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Version");
dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@LocationX);
foreach(FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("#", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Root"] = file.Directory.Name; 
    dr["File_Name"] = file.Name;
    dr["File_Type"] = file.Extension;
    dr["File_Size"] = (file.Length / 1024).ToString();
    dr["Create_Date"] = file.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: Thx. It works the same booth ways if it is in the loop or out of the loop.

Comment: @anzes sure, but you will not check `if (i == 0)` on each loop

Comment: we'll I didn't copied the entire code, I need this because of the checkboxes I'm adding in every row.

Comment: @anzes I've added updated full code with columns creation before loop. Also you can use DirectoryInfo to get FileInfo entries.

Comment: Do I have to use some other library for DirectoryInfo?